# url aspx in composent ascx

Tags: asp.net, url, webforms, ashx

I have a web page search.aspx which list elements in a html table with some search criterias pass in url params. In this page, I call a pagination.ascx composant for pagination which is in a folder user_controls, and i pass the url for next and precedent pages. Did a simplified sample of my code :

search.aspx.cs :

```
public partial class search : IntranetPage
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var paginationControl = (Pagination)LoadControl("UserControl/Pagination.ascx");
        paginationControl.urlNextPage = @"search.aspx?param1=test1&param2=test2";
        Pagination.Controls.Add(paginationControl);
    }
}
```

search.aspx (in folder UserControl/Pagination.ascx) :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="IntranetCompil.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="search.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Back.search" ClientIDMode="Static" %>

<asp:Content ID="search" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="Server">
    <p>Pagination module :</p>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Pagination" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> 
</asp:Content>
```

Pagination.ascx.cs :

```
{
    public partial class Pagination : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string urlNextPage { get; set; } = "defaultUrl";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            link1.HRef = urlNextPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Pagination.ascx :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Back.UserControl.Pagination" CodeBehind="Pagination.ascx.cs"%>
<p>This is a test</p>
<a id="link1"  href="urlNextPage" runat="server" >Next page</a>
```

My probleme is that in the search.aspx, the href is not :

```
search.aspx?param1=test1&param2=test2
```

but

```
/user_controls/search.aspx?param1=test1&param2=test2
```

How can i display the right url in the composant ?

Comment: Well, either the UC on its own page load gets/grabs the URL (parameters) and pulls out the value(s), or on the page load load with the UC, you will have created some public properties of the UC that the page load can set.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, thanks for your repsonse, yes, i pass the url by public property, 
but I don't understand how to avoid having the usercontrol path in the url.

Comment: While like any control, a UC is injected to the current page - and thus URL's should not change. But, of course controls in the UC are prefexed with the control (just like controls inside of a listview or repeater are - since you would have control name conflicts if this was not the case.  (but, I see your solution below - yes, making all URL's referenced from the root folder will make this work (in fact I always do that, and was perplexed as to why your having a issue anyway). But, everyone here appreciates that you followed up with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So i founded a basic solution, in the Pagination.ascx.cs, I sended the url prefixed quite simply by "../" :

```
public partial class Pagination : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string urlNextPage { get; set; } = "defaultUrl";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        link1.HRef = "../"+urlNextPage;
    }
}
```